# How to make a "fake" carrousel js

Tags: javascript, jquery

here's my problem. Maybe I don't find the good logic and that's why I'm here.

So, I would like to make a "fake carrousel".

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <img src="" />
   <img src="" />
  </li>
  <li>
   <img src="" />
   <img src="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

The point is: How to make the first li fadeOut and then fadeIn the second li Infinite time !  I can't find the good logic :( ...

Comment: You looking for **setInterval** JavaScript function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you could do something like this:

```
ul li:first-child { display: block; }
ul li:last-child { display: none; }
ul.alt li:first-child { display: none; }
ul.alt li:last-child { display: block; }
```

Then in JS

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('ul').toggleClass('alt');
}, 300);
```

Comment: Ok, it's exactly what I'm looking for, now, my turn to make it prettier with a fade ! It was this logic I miss :) !

Answer (score 0):

So you want to show li #1 for a set amount of time, then show li #2 for an infinite amount of time?

If so, try something like this:

```
ul = $('ul');
ul.children('li').hide();
ul.children('li:eq(0)').show();

setTimeout(function(){
    ul.children('li:eq(0)').hide();
    ul.children('li:eq(1)').show();
},2000);
```